# crear un div re escalable y movible

Tags: javascript, html, css

necesito tener esta funcionalidad para crear una interfaz de usuario mas amigable, los estoy intentando hacer con javascript puro pero surgen algunos problemas al re escalar el div, el tamaño de este se agranda mucho al hacer el primer click, se supone que el tamaño debería variar mientras se mantiene el boton presionado y al soltarlo debe quedar con el tamaño que se define al mover el mouse.

la primera parte del código no esta funcionando perfectamente ya que el div se mueve, donde esta dando problemas es al final del código ,la función move busca la posición del mouse y reescala el div con esos valores mientras se mantenga presionado el clic de mouse y la funcion stop detecta cuando se deja de dar clic y detiene el movimiento.

por favor ayúdenme con esto.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>


#mydiv {
  resize: both; 
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;

}

#mydivheader {

  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
#resca{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      right: 0px;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>div movible y reescalable</h1>

<p>clic en la cabezera para mover</p>
<button id="crear">Crear Div</button>
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">clic aqui para mover<input type="button" value="cerrar">
</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
  <button id="resca">click para reescalar</button>
</div>

<script>
//hacer el div movible:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
        var divmove = document.getElementById('mydiv');
      var botonCerrar = document.querySelector('input[value="cerrar"]');
      botonCerrar.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        document.getElementById('mydiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';;
    }, false);
    var botonabrir = document.getElementById('crear');
      botonabrir.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      if (divmove.style.visibility === "visible") {
        divmove.style.visibility = "hidden";
      } else {
        divmove.style.visibility = "visible";
      }  
    }, false);


}

function move() {
    document.onmousemove=function(e){
    var largo = document.getElementById("mydiv").style.height="500px";
    var ancho = document.getElementById("mydiv").style.width="500px";  
    e=e || event;
    x=e.clientX;
    y=e.clientY;
    document.getElementById("mydiv").style.height=y+"px";
    document.getElementById("mydiv").style.width=x+"px";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("resca").onmousedown=move;

  function stop() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
    }
    document.getElementById("resca").onmouseup=stop;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace un tiempo hice algo para mi uso que quizás te sirva de ayuda ya que pasé por cosas similares. Resultó complicado ya que también es interfase de web API.

Te puedo decir que me ayudó utilizar porcentajes en muchos valores en vez de pixeles.
También utilicé el "tag" de página

en vez de  para facilitar la fluidez de la página. Aquí el enlace http://s94441163.onlinehome.us/RAMON/CONTENT/Atch/Atch/YtE.htm y abajo parte del código.

```js
function setZoom() {
var Zset = document.getElementById('Zoom').value;
var Zb = Zset - 0;

document.getElementById('Vid').setAttribute('style','font-size:'+Zb+'%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:'+Zb+'%;height:'+Zb+'%');
document.getElementById('Vid').scrollIntoView();
return false;
}
```

```html
<button class="MyBtn" name="ZoomDown" id="ZoomDown" title="Zoom Down &#10; Video" onclick="Zoom.value=(parseInt(Zoom.value))-10;setZoom();return false;" ><</button>
<input id="Zoom" name="Zoom" size="2" title="Zoom Value" value="90" onclick="this.select()" onKeyPress="return checkIt(event)" onchange="" type="text" >
<button class="MyBtn" name="ZoomUp" id="ZoomUp" title="Zoom Up &#10; Video" onclick="Zoom.value=(parseInt(Zoom.value))+10;setZoom();return false;" >></button>

<button class="MyBtn" name="GObtn" id="GObtn" title="Reload &#10; Text" onclick="setLines();document.getElementById('Vid').innerHTML=document.getElementById('Embed').value;Vid.scrollIntoView();return false" >GO</button> &nbsp;




<center>
<!-- 
Below the P tag added the select() script but not the focus() as seems to get the focus
 -->
<hr style="Position:relative; top:-4;left:3;">
<p class="MyVidF" id="Vid" name="Vid" title="Click for Video or Page Focus" onclick="document.getElementById('Vid').scrollIntoView();return false">

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


Video Will Show in this Area.<br>
Refresh page if there's problems.<br>
Thanks!

</p></center>

<hr style="Position:relative; top:-14;left:3;">


<center>
```

Espero te ayude, 
Ramón